# Movie about a secret room with skeletal remains of an old man

Tags: movie, horror, ghost, story-identification

Guess I watched this in the late 90s. Remember only a few things -

There is a girl in a huge old fashioned house. She found a book which had a nicely crafted cover. The cover had a heart shaped piece attached to it. That actually was a key to a secret room. The girl found this out and opened the room where she saw the skeletal remains of an old man. The girl (and her friends?) cremated the remains and freed the old man's soul.

A crow is seen in most of the scenes which flies away in the end.

Comment: Is it a short movie? American?

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember more details. It should be either American or European. The actors were Caucasian!

Comment: Makes me think of one of the adaptations of '[The Canterville Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Canterville_Ghost#Adaptations)' a bit.. But they tend to have the ghost wandering around trying to scare the family (and, instead, being pranked by the children) as a main plot element, too.  At least a few of them have his skeletal body in a secret room, where he was chained up and allowed to starve to death.

Comment: I think that's answered a question I've had for ages.  I saw a ghost movie back in the 80s that scared the bejeezus out of me.  I thought it was the Canterville Ghost, but then it came on the TV and was some animated thing I didn't recognise.  It looks like I must have been scared by the 1985 or 1986 version, and the animated thing was the 1988 version.